# Appearance in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin

I could not able to handle the following assignment in the Xamarin.

I am trying to convert to objective -c code to the Xamarin as follows, but I am getting an error.

Here is the **Objective-C** code:

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Here is my attempt in **Xamarin.iOS**

[image]

Comment: That's because the Appearance object is not a member of UIPageControl, it's a different class that conforms to the appearance protocol.

Comment: How could I able to solve it? If you check my updated question, there is quite similar implementation but getting that error.

Comment: I don't use Xamarin, but I found this with a super quick google search (you should google your questions before asking them) https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Appearance API](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/)

```
UIPageControl.Appearance.PageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.White;
UIPageControl.Appearance.CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.Red;
```